# Write the SQL Server Restore task results to the text file using T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-restore

I have restored one of my backup files from the database `sales` from the Dev to Test and I was required to send the log file to the team lead showing that the task was accomplished.

I tried using different tables but I can see it only in SSMS but not in the log file. I need help with a T-SQL query that can write that restore job to the log file.

All I need in that has to cover the time taken to restore and all the regular that a DBA looks in the Database Restore.

Answer (score 1):

This site:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1860/identify-when-a-sql-server-database-was-restored-the-source-and-backup-date/

contains this query:

```
SELECT [rs].[destination_database_name], 
[rs].[restore_date], 
[bs].[backup_start_date], 
[bs].[backup_finish_date], 
[bs].[database_name] as [source_database_name], 
[bmf].[physical_device_name] as [backup_file_used_for_restore]
FROM msdb..restorehistory rs
INNER JOIN msdb..backupset bs
ON [rs].[backup_set_id] = [bs].[backup_set_id]
INNER JOIN msdb..backupmediafamily bmf 
ON [bs].[media_set_id] = [bmf].[media_set_id] 
ORDER BY [rs].[restore_date] DESC
```

You should also be able to find info in the SQL Server log - more info here:

https://sqlserver-help.com/2011/06/26/help-where-is-sql-server-errorlog/
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187109.aspx

In future you should restore using a script and copy/paste the output ofthe script and send that to the team.

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured database mail, then this should work:

```
USE MASTER;

EXEC MSDB.DBO.SP_SEND_DBMAIL
  @profile_name = 'ProfileName',
  @recipients = 'Recipent',
  @query = '
       RESTORE DATABASE [DBName] FROM
       DISK = N''Path to backup file'' WITH  FILE = 1,
       MOVE N''DBFileName_Data'' TO N''Path to database file'',
       MOVE N''LogFileName_Log'' TO N''Path to log file'',
       NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 5;
       GO',
  @subject = 'Restore report',
  @attach_query_result_as_file = 0,
  @body_format = 'TEXT';

GO
```